# How do I store the contents of tables rows and use them on another page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I am a beginner to web development and am just wondering how I can store the values of a table row and use them on another page.

At the moment I am retrieving values from a database and putting them into a table. Each row has a submit button which should take them to a pay.php page where it should list the details of the particular row that they selected to pay.

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo "<td>" . $row['P_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['P_amount'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['P_dateStart'] . "</td>";
      if(is_null($row['P_datePaid'])){
        echo "<td>Not Paid</td>";
      }
      else{
        echo "<td>" . $row['P_datePaid'] . "</td>";
      }
      if($row['P_status'] == 0){
        echo "<td bgcolor='#FF0000'>" . $row['P_status'] . "</td>";
      }
      else{
        echo "<td bgcolor='#00FF00'>" . $row['P_status'] . "</td>";
      }
      echo "<td><form name = 'viewMore' action = 'viewMore.php'><input type = 'submit' value = 'View More'></form></td>";
      echo "<td><form name = 'pay' action = 'pay.php'><input type = 'submit' value = 'Pay'></form></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";   
?>
```

Comment: you can use session for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks mate, is that the only way?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: You can use data posting using Forms i.e using query strings or you can use session..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the record ID (assuming in my example that is `P_id`) in the form like this. I also added `method='post'` to avoid someone to try `pay.php?id=...` :

```
echo "<td><form name = 'pay' action = 'pay.php' method='post'>
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['P_id'] . "'>
      <input type = 'submit' value = 'Pay'></form></td>";
```

And then in `pay.php` using `$_POST["id"]` to query the table and retrieve the data.

Comment: I changed it from $_GET to $_POST by adding `method='post'` in the `<form>` to block url like `pay.php?id=...`

Answer (score 0):

You can google `PHP Session`

Here is an example.

```
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['views']=1;
```

on another page you can use

```
echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
```

and I think your requirement is not releted to session.
Do you know how to use the form?

You should post the data of the certain line to the page you want.
And you can get the in _POST['XXXX'];